# CSS media query correct usage

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

This question may be very basic but I am new to this kind of things. I have just discovered media queries and I am going to update my website to make it friendly for every device.

```
@media screen and (max-width:960px) { 
...    
}

@media (min-width:961px) { 
... 
}
```

I have decided to set up these breakpoints because my website has a good look if the size is >= 960px. Otherwhise I need to change the CSS and set up a mobile-friendly layout.

---

**Question**

The code above is fine and I have different css styles when I use my laptop or smartphone/tablet. I have noticed that when the width is exactly 960px there is a problem: I cannot see css styles applied.

I mean that if I resize the page to 960px it looks like if there are no css rules. You can check this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tq8wcjcw/). As you can see I have 2 divs and they are displayed according with the rules of the media queries.

Any idea?

Comment: Everything is fine at my end. I tried to change background color and it was reflecting at 960px, then what is the issue?

Comment: Check this one, https://jsfiddle.net/tq8wcjcw/1/

Comment: Your html is broken. Check out http://onlinewebcheck.com to see errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot see css styles applied."? Which style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your media query is saying:

-

### (Query A)

"At 960px, stop displaying this CSS."

### (Query B)

"At 961px, start showing this CSS."

-

Tweaking Query A to `max-width: 961px` and making sure Query B starts with `@media screen and` should fix it.

Comment: For your information, media query did not work like that.. Media query is actually working at 960px.

Comment: check my example. he is saying not working what to do while i have given an fiddle which is showing that it does work. Please don't post low quality answer which will lead another user to wrong direction. Sorry but your answer is totally wrong.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: If for any reason you invert the position of the media queries you will get unexpected results. One will override the other by cascade if you follow this answer. @RaffaeleRossi there is an incorrect symbol in the anchor tag. Please verify this. The media queries are fine, the problem is your markup incorrect syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If your website has a good look if the size is >= 960px, then you have to redefine styles for smaller sizes. So it has to be 959px.
Although if you're not planning to expand a quantity of `@media` blocks, you can use the trick: remove a line `@media (min-width:961px)` and move its content to top of style-sheet before `@media screen and (max-width:960px) {...}` and change 960 to 959 so it has to look like:

```
/* default styles*/
...
@media screen and (max-width:959px) { 
...    
}
```